# how to use sqs.makeUnauthenticatedRequest in promise?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, amazon-sqs

I need to send message via `makeUnauthenticatedRequest()` to sqs and wait for answer, but when I'm tring to set the parameters it returns error.

It is possible to do it in promise? if not, how can I use async-await with `makeUnauthenticatedRequest()`?
thanks.

```
async function send(message) {
    const params = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        DelaySeconds: 0,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sqs.makeUnauthenticatedRequest({ **"sendMessage", params** // cant add those parameters here
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: TS2345: Argument of type '{ "sendMessage": any; params: { MessageBody: string; QueueUrl: string; DelaySeconds: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. @BlackBrain

Comment: Your promise implementation is correct but you are calling makeUnauthenticatedRequest with wrong parameters. It expects a string but you are passing to it a object

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry.. it's very late but solution is:

sqs.makeUnauthenticatedRequest('sendMessage', params).promise()